# How to make TimeLine just like Instagram with multiple Images and Video and Autoplay Back?

Tags: android, android-adapter, exoplayer, autoplay, nestedrecyclerview

[image]

I am implementing Timeline just like Instagram, but i have multiple tabs as i mentioned in the picture. and each tab have separate fragments. Each single fragment have a RecyclerView for multiple Post and i made an adapter for rendering list. i passed the list in adapter and each post item can have multiple images and videos so i make another RecyclerView in single_post_item and made another Adapter for rendering post media. I made a single View Holder for multiple post in first adapter and then i called another adapter from that ViewHolder. In Post Media Adapter i made two view holders one for Images and Other for Videos. i used Exo Player in for playing Videos. the thing which is not resolving is that if i have videos in two consecutive post items it playing video for both items. so how can i handle this scenario. Waiting for the great response from you guys. Thanks in Advance

AllStoriesFragment.java

```
    public class AllStoriesFragment extends DaggerFragment implements OnStoryFetchListener {
        private HomeActivity activity;
        private FragmentAllStoriesBinding binding;
        private List<StoriesResponse> storiesResponseList=new ArrayList<>();
        private AllStoriesAdapter adapter;
        private List<MediaAttachment> mediaAttachments=new ArrayList<>();
        @Inject
        StoriesRepository storiesRepository;
        private List<Stories> allStoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<StoriesMediaItems> storiesMediaItems=new ArrayList<>();
        private Boolean scrollToTop = false;
        @Inject
        TTViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
        StoriesViewModel storiesViewModel;
        private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            activity = (HomeActivity) context;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_all_stories, container, false);

            return binding.getRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            storiesViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(StoriesViewModel.class);
            storiesViewModel.getLatestAllStories(0, AllStoriesFragment.this);
                            storiesViewModel.getAllStories().observe(this,stories -> {
                if (storiesResponseList == null || adapter == null) {
                    setAdapter();
                }
                DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new StoriesDiffCallback(allStoriesList, stories));
                diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
                storiesResponseList.clear();
                allStoriesList.clear();
                //allStoriesList.addAll(stories != null ? stories : new ArrayList<>());
                allStoriesList = stories;
                for (int i=0;i<allStoriesList.size();i++){
                    storiesMediaItems = storiesViewModel.getAllStoryMedia(allStoriesList.get(i).getId());
                    storiesResponseList.add(new StoriesResponse(allStoriesList.get(i).getPostedBy(),allStoriesList.get(i).getPostedByName(),allStoriesList.get(i).getId(),allStoriesList.get(i).getLikesCount(),allStoriesList.get(i).getCommentsCount(),allStoriesList.get(i).getShareCount(),allStoriesList.get(i).getTimeStamp(),allStoriesList.get(i).getLiked(),storiesMediaItems));
                }
                if(adapter == null){
                    setAdapter();
                }
                else {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (scrollToTop) {
                    if (storiesResponseList.size() > 0) {
                        binding.allStoriesListView.scrollToPosition(0);
                    }
                    scrollToTop = false;
                }
            });
        }


        private void setAdapter(){
            if (storiesResponseList == null) {
                this.storiesResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            binding.allStoriesListView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            binding.allStoriesListView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
            adapter= new AllStoriesAdapter(activity,activity,getChildFragmentManager(),storiesResponseList,storiesRepository);
            binding.allStoriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStoryFetched(boolean asc) {
            scrollToTop = asc;
            if (binding.swiperefresh != null && binding.swiperefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                binding.swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            binding.fetchStoriesProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(adapter!=null) {
                StoriesViewHolder view = (StoriesViewHolder) binding.allStoriesListView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adapter.getPosition());
                if (view != null && view.adapter.player!=null) {
                    view.adapter.player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(adapter!=null) {
                StoriesViewHolder view = (StoriesViewHolder) binding.allStoriesListView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adapter.getPosition());
                if (view != null && view.adapter.player!=null) {
                    view.adapter.player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            //storiesRepository.deleteAllStoryAndStoryMedia();
            if(adapter!=null) {
                StoriesViewHolder view = (StoriesViewHolder) binding.allStoriesListView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adapter.getPosition());
                if (view != null && view.adapter.player!=null) {
                    view.adapter.releasePlayer();
                }
            }
            storiesResponseList.clear();
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            linearLayoutManager = null;
            scrollToTop = false;
            storiesViewModel = null;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

AllStoriesAdapter.java

```
public class AllStoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoriesViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<StoriesResponse> storiesResponseList;
private HomeActivity activity;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private int position;

public AllStoriesAdapter(HomeActivity activity, Context context, FragmentManager manager, List<StoriesResponse> storiesResponseList, StoriesRepository storiesRepository) {
    this.context = context;
    this.storiesResponseList = storiesResponseList;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.fragmentManager = manager;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    StoriesItemLayoutBinding itemBinding = StoriesItemLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
    return new StoriesViewHolder(itemBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StoriesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bind(storiesResponseList.get(position), this, fragmentManager, activity);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return storiesResponseList.size();
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

/*@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull StoriesViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    holder.binding.moreOptions.setOnClickListener(null);
    if(holder.adapter!=null) {
        holder.adapter.releasePlayer();
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(StoriesViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    if(holder.adapter!=null) {
        holder.adapter.releasePlayer();
    }
}


public StoriesResponse getLastItemInList() {
    return storiesResponseList.get(storiesResponseList.size() - 1);
}
```

}

StoriesViewHolder.java

```
public class StoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public StoriesItemLayoutBinding binding;
    public int dotsCount;
    //private StoriesMediaPagerAdapter adapter;
    public StoriesMediaRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> dots;
    private Context context;
    private List<StoriesMediaItems> storyItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public StoriesViewHolder(StoriesItemLayoutBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public void bind(StoriesResponse response, AllStoriesAdapter adapter, FragmentManager manager, HomeActivity activity) {
        binding.setStories(response);
        binding.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
        context = activity;
        setUpStoriesAttachmentPager(response.getList(),activity,manager);
    }

    private void setUpStoriesAttachmentPager(List<StoriesMediaItems> storyItems, HomeActivity activity,FragmentManager manager) {
        this.storyItemsList = storyItems == null ? new ArrayList<>() : storyItems;
        binding.storiesItemPager.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        adapter = new StoriesMediaRecyclerViewAdapter(activity, storyItemsList, false);
        binding.storiesItemPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.storiesItemPager.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        binding.storiesItemPager.setOnFlingListener(null);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.storiesItemPager);
        binding.dotsContainer.attachToRecyclerView(binding.storiesItemPager, snapHelper);
        if (storyItemsList.size() == 1) {
            binding.dotsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            binding.dotsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

StoriesMediaRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class StoriesMediaRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 1, TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private List<StoriesMediaItems> storiesMediaItemsList;
    private Context context;
    private String tag = "";
    Boolean isFromComment = false;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private MediaSource mediaSource;
    private DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;
    private DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;
    private int position = -1;

    public StoriesMediaRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<StoriesMediaItems> storiesMediaItemsList,Boolean isFromComment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.storiesMediaItemsList = storiesMediaItemsList;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.isFromComment = isFromComment;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if (viewType == TYPE_IMAGE) {
            StoriesImageViewBinding itemBinding = StoriesImageViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
            return new ImageViewHolder(itemBinding);
        } else {
            StoriesVideoViewBinding itemBinding = StoriesVideoViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
            return new VideoViewHolder(itemBinding);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        StoriesMediaItems storiesMediaItems = storiesMediaItemsList.get(position);
        if (holder instanceof ImageViewHolder) {
            ImageViewHolder imageHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
            Log.d("StoriesTelloImageViewHolder","ImageViewHolder");
            setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            imageHolder.storiesImageViewBinding.captionView.setText(storiesMediaItems.getCaption());
            imageHolder.storiesImageViewBinding.storiesImage.setImageURI(storiesMediaItems.getSourceUrl());
            imageHolder.storiesImageViewBinding.storiesImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(storiesMediaItems.getThumbImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), decodedByte);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(storiesMediaItems.getSourceUrl()))
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(image))
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageHolder.storiesImageViewBinding.storiesImage);

            imageHolder.storiesImageViewBinding.storiesImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isFromComment) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StoriesImageViewerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("storiesMedia", storiesMediaItems);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StoriesCommentsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("storyId", storiesMediaItemsList.get(position).getStoriesId());
                        intent.putExtra("Tag", storiesMediaItemsList.get(position).getTAG());
                        intent.putExtra("storyposition", position);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            VideoViewHolder videoHolder = (VideoViewHolder) holder;
            Log.d("StoriesTelloVideoViewHolder","VideoViewHolder");
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(storiesMediaItemsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getThumbImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), decodedByte);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(image)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(videoHolder.itemBinding.videoPlayerThumbnail);
        }
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        StoriesImageViewBinding storiesImageViewBinding;

        public ImageViewHolder(StoriesImageViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.storiesImageViewBinding = binding;
        }
    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        StoriesVideoViewBinding itemBinding;

        public VideoViewHolder(StoriesVideoViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.itemBinding = binding;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        StoriesMediaItems storiesMediaItems = storiesMediaItemsList.get(position);
        if (storiesMediaItems.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
            return TYPE_IMAGE;
        } else {
            return TYPE_VIDEO;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return storiesMediaItemsList.size();
    }


    public void initializeExoPlayer() {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "TelloTalkStoriesPlayer"), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);
    }

    public void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
            trackSelector = null;
        }
    }

    public MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, VideoViewHolder holder) {
        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,
                mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        holder.itemBinding.videoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        return mediaSource;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        Log.d("StoriesTelloOnViewRecycled","onViewRecycled");
        //releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        Log.d("StoriesTelloOnAttachedToRecyclerView","onAttachedToRecyclerView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        Log.d("StoriesTelloOnDetachedFromRecyclerView","onDetachedFromRecyclerView");
        //releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        Log.d("StoriesTelloOnViewAttachedToWindow","onViewAttachedToWindow");
        if(holder instanceof ImageViewHolder){
            releasePlayer();
        }
        else if(holder instanceof VideoViewHolder){
            releasePlayer();
            VideoViewHolder videoHolder = (VideoViewHolder) holder;
            initializeExoPlayer();
            setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(storiesMediaItemsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getThumbImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), decodedByte);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(image)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(videoHolder.itemBinding.videoPlayerThumbnail);
            buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(storiesMediaItemsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getSourceUrl()), (VideoViewHolder) holder);
            player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                    if(isLoading){
                        ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                    switch (playbackState)
                    {
                        case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_IDLE:


                            //if (ivPlayPause != null) {
                            //    ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //}
//                            if (player != null) {
//                                player.seekTo(0);
//                                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
//                            }
                            //ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_play);
                            //isPlay = false;
                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_READY:
                            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).itemBinding.videoPlayerThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //ivThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekProcessed() {

                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
        Log.d("StoriesTelloOnViewDetachedFromWindow","onViewDetachedFromWindow");
    }
}
```

Comment: @a_local_nobody included

Comment: Hi, buddy. Have you found any solution?